# ArangoDB REST Traversal return invalid startVertex

Tags: python, graph-databases, arangodb, nosql

I've been trying to do some simple traversal in python using the REST API:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8529/_api/traversal"
d = { "startVertex": 'V/62824208658', "graphName" : "G", "direction" : "outbound"}
r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(d))
print r.json()
```

But this what i get :

```
{u'errorMessage': u'invalid startVertex', u'errorNum': 1202, u'code': 404, u'error': True}
```

I am sure that the vertice and graph exist. I have created them, and connected the vertice to another one by hand using the graphical interface.

Does anyone know why?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem, you are working on a database test_db but your traversal request is adressing the (default) _system db.
Change the call to:

```
url = "http://localhost:8529/_db/test_db/_api/traversal"
```

And don't forget to define a direction ;)

Cheers

Florian

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems quite clear, i took a look at the implementation of *traversal*
and it only returns this error when the vertex is not found in the database.

Just to confirm, try `GET http://localhost:8529/_api/document/V/62824208658` to check if your vertex exists